# ios swift package manager usage: how to reChoose the Firebase libraries you want to use

Tags: ios, firebase, swift-package-manager

Added Firebase package with only FirebaseDatabaseSwift to the project. Now I need FirebaseAuth (and it shows up in the package list even though I did not choose it). When I try to import FirebaseAuth, Xcode gives an error. Is there a way to just add the package that I need or somehow remove the whole thing and add it back while choosing the necessary packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.kiloloco.com/articles/010-add-package-product-xcode/:

- navigate to the **Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content** of your target under the General tab and click +
- Find and select the desired dependency

Comment: That saved removing the whole thing wholesale. Gracias.